# Knapsack with unique elements

Tags: algorithm, language-agnostic, dynamic-programming

I'm trying to solve the following:

> The knapsack problem is as follows: given a set of integers S={s1,s2,…,sn}, and a given target number T, find a subset of S **that adds up exactly to T**. For example, within S={1,2,5,9,10} there is a subset that adds up to T=22 but not T=23. Give a correct programming algorithm for knapsack that runs in O(nT) time.

but the only algorithm I could come up with is generating all the 1 to N combinations and try the sum out (exponential time).

I can't devise a dynamic programming solution since the fact that I can't reuse an object makes this problem different from a coin rest exchange problem and from a general knapsack problem.

Can somebody help me out with this or at least give me a hint?

Comment: For reference, the problem you're describing is usually called the Subset Sum problem.  In the Knapsack problem, each item has a weight *and a value*, and the goal is to maximise the total value for a given maximum allowed total weight.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `O(nT)` running time gives you the hint: do dynamic programming on two axes.  That is, let `f(a,b)` denote the maximum sum <= b which can be achieved with the first `a` integers.

`f` satisfies the recurrence

```
f(a,b) = max( f(a-1,b), f(a-1,b-s_a)+s_a )
```

since the first value is the maximum without using `s_a` and the second is the maximum including `s_a`.  From here the DP algorithm should be straightforward, as should outputting the correct subset of S.

Comment: What exactly is s_a ?

Comment: `s_a` is the `a`'th number in the set `S`

Comment: Uhm, are  you sure the first term f(f(a-1),b) is written properly? f is a function of two variables

Answer (score 0):

I did find a solution but with O(T(n2)) time complexity. If we make a table from bottom to top. In other words If we sort the array and start with the greatest number available and make a table where columns are the target values and rows the provided number. We will need to consider the sum of all possible ways of making i- cost [j] +j . Which will take n^2 time. And this multiplied with target.